# Automatically update links when opening a workbook

Tags: excel, button, vba

My add-in downloads and open a workbook that has a button.
The button calls a macro named CommandBUtton_Click. As shown in the form bellow.

When the user downloads and click on  the button a error message is shown warning that no macro CommandBUtton_Click was found. But If I manually right-click the button and click on assign macro I can make the button work just by removing the path before the macro name.
Is it possible to set a workbook event to automatically remove the path?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user downloads the workbook, I would venture to say that the path to your Click event becomes invalid since that was probably the path on the machine the workbook was created on and may not exist on the users machine. When the event is re-assigned, it's most likely saved in a default local directory, probably Users/current user/AppData/... (Vista +). The easiest way around this is to save the macro to an existing system location on the original workbook.